# How to compute the order of (2, 3) on the elliptic curve y^2 = x^3 + 1?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Since $y^2 = x^3 + 1 $ has a group structure, how could you compute this by Mordell–Weil theorem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent to the curve at $P_1 = (2,3)$ is  $y = 2 x - 1$.  This intersects the curve at $(0,-1)$, so $2 P_1 = (0,1)$.
The line through $2 P_1$ and $P_1$ is $y = x + 1$, which intersects the curve at
$(-1,0)$, so $3 P_1 = (-1,0)$. 
The line tangent to the curve at $3 P_1$ is $x=-1$, which does not intersect 
the curve anywhere else.  Thus $6 P_1$ is the "point at infinity" $O$, and the order of $P_1$ is $6$.